# wp_remote_get doesn't work with secure connections https?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I'm querying the twitter api when I use non secure connection http:// it works fine no wp_error (but twitter exceed limit error) but when I use https:// it works in my browser I can see the json and the xml formats, but there's an error with wp_remote_get, I tried using a second argument array('sslverify' => false) and it doesn't work either ?

so am I doing something wrong or wp_remote_get doesn't work with https ?

here's the code:

```
$response = wp_remote_get('https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/$username.json');
if ( is_wp_error($response) ) {
echo 'wp error';
}
```

when I use http like this url

```
wp_remote_get('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=$username');
```

it works without the error.

I tried wp_remote_get on other apis too but always when using https it doesn't work.

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I'm getting this from var_dump($response):

```
wp errorobject(WP_Error)#359 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["http_request_failed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(146) "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

and after using `array('sslverify' => false)` I'm getting from var_dump($response)

```
wp errorobject(WP_Error)#359 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["http_request_failed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(23) "Empty reply from server" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample URL you are using for the Twitter API without personal data, plus the exact code you are attempting the wp_remote_get with?

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to know what exactly the error is, so rather than echo out a string, use print_r() or var_dump() to dump $response onto the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, just noticed that you're wrapping the URL in single quotes, so the `$username` variable won't get interpreted. Try this instead:

```
wp_remote_get('https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/'. $username .'.json');
```

Or use double quotes instead of single.

Comment: thank you very much :) I've seen something like {$username} inside urls what's the difference ?

Comment: You'll still have to use double quotes when wrapping a variable in curly braces. In WP, you'll see that a lot in database calls, like this {$wpdb->prefix}some_table_name. In that case it's being used to declare the end of the variable name.

Here's the link to the relevant PHP manual page:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex